# How to delete .pack and .idx file using QT

Tags: git, qt

I am able to delete whole content of .git folder except .pack and .idx files using below code on windows 7 OS :

```
QString strpath = QDir::homePath() + "/Repo/.git/";
    QDir dirForDeleteGit = strpath;
    QStringList strlistForGitDelete = dirForDeleteGit.entryList();

    for (int i=0; i<strlistForGitDelete.count(); i++)
     {
       QString strForGitFilePath = strpath + strlistForGitDelete.at(i);
       QFileInfo fileinfoForGit (strForGitFilePath);


      if(fileinfoForGit.isDir())
       {
         QStringList strlistForDeleteGit(strForGitFilePath);
         QDirIterator it(strForGitFilePath,QDir::Executable| QDir::Hidden| QDir::AllEntries|QDir::System |QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Hidden | QDir::Files,QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

         if(it.hasNext())
         {
           while(it.hasNext())
           {
             strlistForDeleteGit << it.next();
           }

           int gitCount = strlistForDeleteGit.count()-1;
           qDebug()<<"File count :"<<gitCount;
           for(int j=gitCount; j>=0; j--)
           {
             QFileInfo fileinfor(strlistForDeleteGit.at(j));
              if(fileinfor.isDir())
               {
                  QDir dir(strlistForDeleteGit.at(j));
                   qDebug()<<"dir :"<<strlistForDeleteGit.at(j);
                  dir.rmdir(strlistForDeleteGit.at(j));
               }
              else
              {
                  QFile file(strlistForDeleteGit.at(j));
                   qDebug()<<"File :"<<strlistForDeleteGit.at(j);
                  file.remove(strlistForDeleteGit.at(j));
              }
                }
               }
         else
         {
             QDir dir(strForGitFilePath);
             dir.rmdir(strForGitFilePath.at(i));
         }
           }
      else
      {
          QFile file (strForGitFilePath);
          file.remove();
      }
   }
```

Any suggestion/resolution ? I want to delete complete content of .git folder. I have tried by using different different flags for QDirIterator.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not "debugging helper" service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - it is not clear, what problem do you have: 1) you didn't read Qt documentation? 2) you don't know programming basics: how to write loops and use if-else operator? 3) other? You need to put a breakpoint to first line of your code and do a step-by-step debugging.

Comment: So what went wrong? Which qt function did not do what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the resolution by set permission of file. Before deleting .idx and .pack file I use `file.setPermissions(QFile::WriteOther);`. This successfully deleted the files on Win7 OS.